# Mutually-exclusive TikZ .is choice keys

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfkeys

My TikZ drawing package has a command that will draw a "simple beam", which is basically a rectangle between two arbitrary points. The code below is the relevant part from the package:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% Sets various configuration parameters
% \strandlibset[module]{options as pgfkeys}
\NewDocumentCommand{\strandlibset}{o m}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
    \pgfqkeys{/strandlib}{#2}
  }
  {
    \pgfqkeys{/strandlib/#1}{#2}
  }
}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@beam@start@round
\newif\if@beam@start@butt
\newif\if@beam@start@rect
\newif\if@beam@end@round
\newif\if@beam@end@butt
\newif\if@beam@end@rect
\pgfkeys{
  /strandlib/beam/.is family,
  /strandlib/beam,
  thickness/.initial=1mm,
  color/.initial=blue,
  @style/.style={/tikz, draw=#1, fill=#1!50!white, thick},
  start/.is choice,
  start/butt/.is if=@beam@start@butt,
  start/rect/.is if=@beam@start@rect,
  start/round/.is if=@beam@start@round,
  start/butt=false,
  start/rect=true,
  start/round=false,
  start=rect,
  end/.is choice,
  end/butt/.is if=@beam@end@butt,
  end/rect/.is if=@beam@end@rect,
  end/round/.is if=@beam@end@round,
  end/butt=false,
  end/rect=true,
  end/round=false,
  end=rect,
}
% \simplebeam[*both rounded]{start}{end}[additional options]
\NewDocumentCommand{\simplebeam}{s m m o}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfValueT{#4}{
    \strandlibset[beam]{#4}
  }
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{
    \strandlibset[beam]{start=round, end=round}
  }
  \if@beam@start@butt
    \coordinate (beamCentreA) at (#2);
  \else
    \coordinate (beamCentreA) at ($(#2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!180:(#3)$);
  \fi
  \if@beam@end@butt
    \coordinate (beamCentreB) at (#3);
  \else
    \coordinate (beamCentreB) at ($ (#3)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!180:(#2)$);
  \fi
  \coordinate (beamCornerA1) at ($ (beamCentreA)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!90:(beamCentreB)$);
  \coordinate (beamCornerA2) at ($ (beamCentreA)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!-90:(beamCentreB)$);
  \coordinate (beamCornerB1) at ($ (beamCentreB)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!-90:(beamCentreA)$);
  \coordinate (beamCornerB2) at ($ (beamCentreB)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!90:(beamCentreA)$);
  \if@beam@start@round
    \if@beam@end@round
      \filldraw[/strandlib/beam/@style=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/color}, rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}] (beamCornerA1) -- (beamCornerA2) -- (beamCornerB2) -- (beamCornerB1) -- cycle;
    \else
      \filldraw[/strandlib/beam/@style=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/color}, rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}] (beamCornerA1) -- (beamCornerA2) [sharp corners] -- (beamCornerB2) -- (beamCornerB1) [rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}] -- cycle;
    \fi
  \else
    \if@beam@end@round
      \filldraw[/strandlib/beam/@style=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/color}] (beamCornerA1) -- (beamCornerA2) [rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}] -- (beamCornerB2) -- (beamCornerB1) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
    \else
      \filldraw[/strandlib/beam/@style=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/color}] (beamCornerA1) -- (beamCornerA2) -- (beamCornerB2) -- (beamCornerB1) -- cycle;
    \fi
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Variety of options: some round, some not.
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \strandlibset[beam]{color=red}
        \simplebeam{0, 0}{4, 0}
        \simplebeam{0, 2}{5, 2}[thickness=2mm, start=round, end=round]
        \simplebeam{0, 3}{3, 6}[start=butt, end=round]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

All round!
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \strandlibset[beam]{color=black!50!white, start=round, end=round}
        \simplebeam{0, 0}{4, 0}
        \simplebeam{0, 2}{5, 2}[thickness=2mm, start=rect, end=rect]
        \simplebeam{0, 5}{2, 3}[start=butt, end=round, thickness=1.5mm]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that if I globally set the beam ends to round (e.g. using `\strandlibset[beam]{start=round, end=round}`), then I can't change that for a single instance of a beam (e.g. `\simplebeam{A}{B}[end=butt]`), because the `@beam@start@round` is `true`. Essentially what I need is for the `start/.is choice` and `end/.is choice` keys to turn off the other booleans: `start=butt` should imply that `@start@round = false` and `@start@rect = false`. What's actually happening is that `start=butt` simply sets `@start@butt = true` but doesn't change the other two boolean flags.

How can I fix this?

Some alternate method that achieves the same result would also be accepted, as the nested if-statements are somewhat awkward.

Comment: Why do you have two separate keys for start and end if they should be synchronized? It seems as if you only need one `/.is choice` key that can take the values `butt`, `rect` and `round`, which determine the line cap on both sides.

Comment: The reason for two keys for the start and end is because sometimes I'll want a beam that has a different cap on each side, e.g. `round` at the start but `rect` at the end. The reason I'm posting this question is precisely because of this: I've got a drawing where all the beams except two are round, and those two have a `butt` cap at one end.

Comment: Extract from PDF specifications: "_The line cap style shall specify the shape that shall be used at the ends of open subpaths (and dashes, if any)
when they are stroked._"  A stroked path uses only *one* line cap style!

Comment: @PaulGaborit Good point! One can still add arrow heads that provide these line caps. This might also the way to go in the answer.

Comment: I figured out a solution: in the `\if@beam@start@butt`, add a `\boolfalse{@beam@start@round}` after defining the beam center A coordinate, and likewise for the `\if@beam@end@butt`.

I'm able to sidestep the PDF specifications because while the beams look like lines, they're actually implemented as (rotated) rectangles.

Comment: @Robbie Can you provide a full MWE?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposition using the `.code` handler to manage three booleans as radio buttons (as exclusive choices):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% Sets various configuration parameters
% \strandlibset[module]{options as pgfkeys}
\NewDocumentCommand{\strandlibset}{o m}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
    \pgfqkeys{/strandlib}{#2}
  }
  {
    \pgfqkeys{/strandlib/#1}{#2}
  }
}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@beam@start@round
\newif\if@beam@start@butt
\newif\if@beam@start@rect
\newif\if@beam@end@round
\newif\if@beam@end@butt
\newif\if@beam@end@rect
\pgfkeys{
  /strandlib/beam/.is family,
  /strandlib/beam,
  thickness/.initial=1mm,
  color/.initial=blue,
  @style/.style={/tikz, draw=#1, fill=#1!50!white, thick},
  start/.is choice,
  start/butt/.code={
    \@beam@start@butttrue
    \@beam@start@rectfalse
    \@beam@start@roundfalse
  },
  start/rect/.code={
    \@beam@start@buttfalse
    \@beam@start@recttrue
    \@beam@start@roundfalse
  },
  start/round/.code={
    \@beam@start@buttfalse
    \@beam@start@rectfalse
    \@beam@start@roundtrue
  },
  end/.is choice,
  end/butt/.code={
    \@beam@end@butttrue
    \@beam@end@rectfalse
    \@beam@end@roundfalse
  },
  end/rect/.code={
    \@beam@end@buttfalse
    \@beam@end@recttrue
    \@beam@end@roundfalse
  },
  end/round/.code={
    \@beam@end@buttfalse
    \@beam@end@rectfalse
    \@beam@end@roundtrue
  },
  % initial values
  start=rect,
  end=rect,
}
% \simplebeam[*both rounded]{start}{end}[additional options]
\NewDocumentCommand{\simplebeam}{s m m o}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfValueT{#4}{
    \strandlibset[beam]{#4}
  }
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{
    \strandlibset[beam]{start=round, end=round}
  }
  \if@beam@start@butt
    \coordinate (beamCentreA) at (#2);
  \else
    \coordinate (beamCentreA) at ($(#2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!180:(#3)$);
  \fi
  \if@beam@end@butt
    \coordinate (beamCentreB) at (#3);
  \else
    \coordinate (beamCentreB) at ($ (#3)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!180:(#2)$);
  \fi
  \coordinate (beamCornerA1) at ($ (beamCentreA)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!90:(beamCentreB)$);
  \coordinate (beamCornerA2) at ($ (beamCentreA)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!-90:(beamCentreB)$);
  \coordinate (beamCornerB1) at ($ (beamCentreB)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!-90:(beamCentreA)$);
  \coordinate (beamCornerB2) at ($ (beamCentreB)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}!90:(beamCentreA)$);
  \if@beam@start@round
    \if@beam@end@round
      \filldraw[/strandlib/beam/@style=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/color}, rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}] (beamCornerA1) -- (beamCornerA2) -- (beamCornerB2) -- (beamCornerB1) -- cycle;
    \else
      \filldraw[/strandlib/beam/@style=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/color}, rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}] (beamCornerA1) -- (beamCornerA2) [sharp corners] -- (beamCornerB2) -- (beamCornerB1) [rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}] -- cycle;
    \fi
  \else
    \if@beam@end@round
      \filldraw[/strandlib/beam/@style=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/color}] (beamCornerA1) -- (beamCornerA2) [rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/thickness}] -- (beamCornerB2) -- (beamCornerB1) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
    \else
      \filldraw[/strandlib/beam/@style=\pgfkeysvalueof{/strandlib/beam/color}] (beamCornerA1) -- (beamCornerA2) -- (beamCornerB2) -- (beamCornerB1) -- cycle;
    \fi
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Variety of options: some round, some not.
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \strandlibset[beam]{color=red}
        \simplebeam{0, 0}{4, 0}
        \simplebeam{0, 2}{5, 2}[thickness=2mm, start=round, end=round]
        \simplebeam{0, 3}{3, 6}[start=butt, end=round]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

All round!
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \strandlibset[beam]{color=black!50!white, start=round, end=round}
        \simplebeam{0, 0}{4, 0}
        \simplebeam{0, 2}{5, 2}[thickness=2mm, start=rect, end=rect]
        \simplebeam{0, 5}{2, 3}[start=butt, end=round, thickness=1.5mm]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks neater if I replace the plain TeX with `etoolbox` LaTeX-type macros, and I'm going through the rest of the code cleaning it up like that. It never ceases to amaze me that other peoples' solutions are obvious answers but ones that just didn't occur to me at the time.